# Text Recognition with RNCamera

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to develop a ReactNative app which uses RNCamera, along with other libraries like react-navigation. Here are the dependencies and their versions that I am using:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-camera": "^3.42.0",
"react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
"react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2"
```

Everything is working just fine, but the problem is that I want to use the live text recognition which does not give me the results expected. This is the code I am using:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';

const CameraScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  state = {
      recordOptions: {
          mute: false,
          maxDuration: 5,
          quality: RNCamera.Constants.VideoQuality['288p'],
      }
  };

  return (
      <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            camera = ref;
          }}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
          }}
          type={'back'}
          flashMode={'off'}
          autoFocus={'on'}
          zoom={0}
          whiteBalance={'auto'}
          ratio={'16:9'}
          focusDepth={0}
          trackingEnabled
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                      title: 'Permission to use camera',
                      message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                      buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                      buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}

          onTextRecognized={({text})=>{console.log(text)}}
      ></RNCamera>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default CameraScreen;
```

As you can see, I call an console.log function for onTextRecognized, which is triggered every few milliseconds. What happens is that I am constantly reciving the text 'undefined', which does not change even if I put text in front of the camera for a minute. This is the logs I got (it can be seen that logs appear every few milliseconds):

[logs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcPjV.png)

Does anybody know how can I get the text without taking a picture?
I also have tried to add 'textBlocks' from other tutorials but I can't make it work (please tell me if you also know how to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was an stupid question, sorry.

The curly brackets that I put in `onTextRecognized={({text})=>{console.log(text)}}` are for extracting specific information from a bigger object. As the 'text' parameter does not exist in the 'textBlocks' object that onTextRecognized returns, the console prints undefined. In order to make it work you actualy have to put {textBlocks} where I put text, like so:

```
onTextRecognized={({textBlocks})=>{console.log(textBlocks)}}
```

Putting that will return the 'textBlocks' object from a bigger 'textBlock'object (they have the same name but the inner 'textBlocks' is easier to use).